# Count the number of times a specific user downloaded files through Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Both my *Post* & *Comment* models have `has_one_attached :file`. What I want to do is to count the number of times a specific user downloaded either a post's file or a comment's file. Create a sort of `download_counter_cache` on the *User* model that increments whenever this user downloads a file. How can I achieve this?

**Update based on Max's answer**

This is what I did for the moment:

```
# Migration file
class CreateDownloads < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :downloads do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :resource, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
# Routes.rb
 concern :downloadable do
   resources :downloads, only: :create
 end

 resources :posts, concerns: :downloadable do
   [...] # Routes such as like/dislike
   resources :comments, concerns: :downloadable do
     [...] # Routes such as like/dislike
   end
 end
```

```
# In posts/_post.html.erb
<%= link_to([@post, :downloads], html_options = {class: 'file w-100'}, method: :post) do %>
  [...]
<% end %>
```

My `downloads_controller` is exactly the same as suggested in Max's answer, as are my Post, Comment, User & Download models.

The problem is that whenever I try to download it redirects me to `downloads#index` which obviously does not exist. I am not sure how I am supposed to create the `resource` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max has a good answer, but if you just want to have only one column on a User model to count all downloads it could be done without a polymorphic join table.

Let's add an attribute to the User module to store the counts:

```rb
  add_column :users, :download_count, :integer
```

Then add a controller that will handle the counts and redirect to a downloaded file:

```rb
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # using find_by so it doesn't throw any errors
    resource = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) || Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id])

    if resource
      current_user.increment!(:download_count)
      redirect_to rails_blob_path(resource.file, disposition: "attachment")
    else
      render nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

Routes will look like:

```rb
  resources :downloads, only: :create
```

Download link in view looks like:

```rb
# for post file
<%= link_to 'download file', downloads_path(post_id: @post.id), method: :post %>

# for comment file
<%= link_to 'download file', downloads_path(comment_id: comment.id), method: :post %>
```

As simple as that.

---

Update: changed the method from new to post to prevent double rendering.

Comment: This would only ever keep track of total number of downloads (of all files) per user and is a lot less useful.

Comment: @max, you are right. It is the most straightforward solution for what the author wants.

Comment: @AleksanderLopez thank you for your reply! I will try your solution if I can't manage to make Max's to work.

Comment: I managed to make your solution work, thank you a lot! I am still interested however in @max's way of doing it as it will give me more flexibility over time. But for the moment, your solution is perfect!

Comment: @AleksanderLopez I was wondering is there anyway, after the download is done, to redirect to `posts#index`?

Comment: Or maybe just some way to reset the url instead of having the Active Storage one for downloading (when clicking on refresh after first download a file, it will download it again)?

Comment: @AleksanderLopez I just realized that `downloads#new` gets called twice, resulting in the `download_cout` getting incremented twice

Comment: @GabrielGuérin I'll check that problem today and will update the answer.

Comment: @GabrielGuérin check the updated answer. Basically I only changed the method from new to post to prevent double rendering.

Comment: @AleksanderLopez it works perfectly, thank you! And the url stays the same, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @GabrielGuérin I'm glad that it worked for you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to start by adding a join table between the user and either the comments/posts table or directly to the activesupport attachments table.

```
class Download
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Post
  has_many :downloads, as: :resource
end

class Comment
  has_many :downloads, as: :resource
end

class User
  has_many :downloads
end
```

You then have to create a rails controller to proxy the downloads as downloading an ActiveSupport attachment will normally bypass your Rails app completely and download straight from the service which stores the attachments such as S3.

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! # I'm assuming you're using Devise
  before_action :set_resource

  def create
    @download = @resource.downloads.create!(user: current_user)
    redirect_to @resource.file.service_url
  end

  def set_resource
    if params[:post_id]
      @resource = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    elsif params[:comment_id]
      @resource = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    end
  end
end
```

```
# routes.rb
concern :downloadable do
  resources :downloads, only: :create
end
resources :posts, concerns: :downloadable
resources :comments, concerns: :downloadable
```

```
<%= button_to "Download", [@post, :downloads], method: :post %>
```

You would then count the downloads by counting the rows in the downloads table.

Comment: By `activesupport attachments table` do you mean this table: `active_storage_attachments`?

Comment: I also don't understand where the `belongs_to :resource` comes from. When you talk about "adding a join table between the user and either the comments/posts table", is this not already the `downloads` table?

Comment: Ok so I did everything you showed here but there is one problem: clicking on the button does not download the file but redirects to `downloads#index` which obviously does not exist.

Comment: downloads is basically just a join table as it just joins the users and posts/comments table. ’belongs_to : resource’ is just a polymorphic association to either a comment or post.

Comment: As to why it's loading the index action, check the logs if it's being sent as a POST request.

Comment: Ok so you were right, the problem was linked to the inappropriate method being called. However, I now get the error `unknown attribute 'resource_id' for Download.` at this line: `@download = @resource.downloads.create!(user: current_user)`. Do you know why?

Comment: Should I create a table called `Resources`? So that I can add a migration to the `downloads_table`?

Comment: I added a a column `resource_id` to the downloads table but then I get another error:  `unknown attribute 'resource_type' for Download`. Could you tell me what is the exact migration I should run when creating the Download & Resource models please?

Comment: `t.belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true`.  You can also just add a `resource_type` string column to the existing table and add an index with `add_index :downloads, [:resource_id, :resource_type]`. Resource is not actually a model - this is just a polymorphic association that points to whatever model you want. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: To generate the whole thing you can run `rails d model download` and then `rails g model download user:belongs_to resource:belongs_to{polymorphic}`.